# Login with api and go to Home page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have login form in flutter and button:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: log_in,
)
```

My log_in function:

```
log_inc() async {

    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    };

    var data = '{"username":"XXXXX", "password":"XXXXX"}';

    var url = Uri.parse('http://XXXXX/api/auth/get_tokens');
    var res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: data);
    if (res.statusCode != 200)
      throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
    var data_res = jsonDecode(res.body);



    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    await storage.write(key: "token", value: data_res["access_token"]);
    var token = await storage.read(key: "token");
    print(token);
    return Home_page();
}
```

Everithing works fine, I'm getting acces token and store it with FlutterSecureStorage but I cannot redirect to Home_page.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to the `Home_page` , you can use the `Navigator` class in Flutter.

```
log_in() async {
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
  };

  var data = '{"username":"XXXXX", "password":"XXXXX"}';

  var url = Uri.parse('http://XXXXX/api/auth/get_tokens');
  var res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: data);
  if (res.statusCode != 200)
    throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
  var data_res = jsonDecode(res.body);

  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  await storage.write(key: "token", value: data_res["access_token"]);

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home_page()),
  );
}
```

Comment: So stupid from me, I;ve tried with: Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Home_page"); but didn't work. Thanks